# Q: Yammer OG from a single page app

Tags: angular, facebook-opengraph, yammer

We have a very big website split up in single page apps all using angular. So on first request you just get the plain html that still needs to be interpolated by angular.

When a user copies an url for an article of some sorts and pastes it into yammer, yammer will start fetching webpage data a.k.a. OG tags. We have provided a large number of different OG tags, but those are only filled in after angular interpolation.

What yammer retrieves is the plain html, which results in yammer grabbing uninterpolated content. Getting things like {{ article.title }} in og:description for example.

We have a SEO engine setup, which works perfectly for the scrapping google, facebook and twitter performs.

Is there anything we can do so yammer can fetch the proper content?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways that Open Graph objects get created. This can be from an activity stream post, explicit message post with OG parameters, or in your case from scraping.

In order for scraping to work, you need to present valid OG metadata in the page presented to the scraper. Any JS to populate client-side pages is not going to get executed, so may need to render the correct values on the server-side. It might be a good idea to test your application with curl, or another HTTP client, to see what is returned.